# Adding an External jar file in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jar, pom.xml

I have a Spring Boot app that am developing and it requires an external jar to use the library.

This is how am adding the external jar;

```
<dependency>
    <artifactId>uptime-sdk</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.uptime.app</groupId>
    <version>2.0.0-ALPHA</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/src/lib/uptime-sdk-fatjar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

The above implementation works when running the app using the embedded Tomcat server in IntelliJ.

But after packaging the app in a .war file and deploy it in a Tomcat server, the app does not work. Instead I get the exception;

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

The exception points to a class found in the external jar.

When I check the files used to generate the .war file, I can't see the external jar in the WEB-INF or the META-INF folders.

Any sort of help or guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's not a good idea of specifying the "Version" tag in spring-boot app. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-dependency-management

Comment: Hi did you find solution of this please help me